# Term for "inverse image" of element under set-valued map?

Tags: analysis, functions, elementary-set-theory, reference-request, terminology

Say I have a function $f: A \to 2^B$. Given an element $b \in B$, I want to refer to the set $f_b := \{a \in A: b \in f(a)\}$.

Is there a standard name for such sets?

Notice it's not technically correct to call it the inverse image of $b$, because of a type mismatch -- the range of $f$ is the subsets of $B$, whereas $b$ is an element of $B$. Also note I'm not asking about $f^{-1}(\{b\})$.

Comment: Typo: I think you want to write $f_b$ instead of $f_a$.

Comment: @ZeroXLR, fixed, thanks!

Comment: is f invertible.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee, not necessarily. In my setting we could have $f(a) = S$ and $f(a') = S$ for $a \neq a'$.

Comment: preimage ? maybe ?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no established terminology for this. If we denote by $\uparrow b = \{U \subseteq B : b \in U\}$, then $f_b = f^{-1}(\uparrow b)$. This set $\uparrow b$ is called the *principal filter at $b$* ([more on filters on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_(mathematics))).

So maybe something like *principal pre-image at $b$* would make sense? You would have to define what that means, but if you use it a lot it can shorten your notation. Or since you have to introduce some new notation anyway, you can use the notation $\uparrow b$ and simply talk about $f^{-1}(\uparrow b)$ or "the pre-image of $\uparrow b$".

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful and I like your suggestion.